# python mysql query with 1 interger value

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm working on a school project and trying to get a mysql query with a interger paramater that will select the id of a movie in my database.

```
t = 1
c.execute("SELECT * FROM films WHERE filmid = %s", (t))
```

I know for a fact that the filmid exist and that er is a filmid with 1.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM films WHERE filmid = %s", (t))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

this is the error code that I am getting. All the tips are welcome.

Comment: I strongly suggest you do: `c.execute("SELECT * FROM films WHERE filmid = {}".format(t))` instead. Or even `c.execute("SELECT * FROM films WHERE filmid = {myInt}".format(myInt=t))`. If the library you're using have auto-parsing of `%x` variables in the string, please supply us with what library you're using. At least I will assume you tried to do `"SELECT * FROM films WHERE filmid = %s" % (t)` otherwise.

Comment: @Torxed thanks it is working now.

Comment: You're welcome :) Best of luck with your studies!

Comment: The 2nd arg to `.execute` should be a tuple; `(t)` isn't a tuple, so you need to change it to `(t,)`. Do **not** inject parameters directly into your query string using string `.format` or other string interpolation techniques. It won't hurt here, but if `t` were some arbitrary data you'd be open to an SQL injection attack.